# Spring integration dsl with multiple listeners on same queue but with different selectors

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to get multiple listeners configured on same queue, but with different message selector. I am using Solace JMS provider.

The behavior is that the first loaded listener will have its selector registered and is receiving the messages.
the second listener is NOT receiving the message. And using Spring integration DSL 1.1.3

what could be wrong?

I tried with two different Queue connection factory, but could not get it working.

How can we have two Selective consumers configured ?

Comment: Thanks for you replies. Looked at the queue configuration for Solace. It had property to enable queue in Exclusive and Non-Exclusive mode. We changed it to Non-exclusive mode. This made it work.  Although the apps are using different Connection Factories. I would like them to use one Connection factory, and in one App. I still need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start from your vendor first of all and try to figure out if it supports concurrent selective consumers.

Although you have to bear in mind that with the `Queue` only one consumer accepts message anyway. So, if first one is able to process the message, the second one won't receive it, even with different selector.

Consider to switch to the `Topic`.

Comment: FYI, I just tested it with activemq and it worked fine.

Comment: Agreed Artem, I am reaching out to jms provider solace jms.  This, I thought to be basic queue routing capability in any provider, to implement selective consumer pattern. The requirement is to route messages based on header value, for which selective consumer on queue seems to be right approach.

Comment: Thanks Gary for confirming with activemq. It helped. I am liking the DSL config, it makes it fast and error-free. Thanks,